# Solving ax^2+bx+c=0 equation using C

Tags: c

**When i Run the program it gives me always imaginary number as answer though i have changed the values of a,b & c **

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
main()
{
float X, X1, X2, d, a,b,c;
printf("Square Equation Solve\n");
printf("\nGive the Values of a,b&c:\n");
scanf("%f%f%",&a,&b,&c);
d=(b*b-(4.0*a*c));

if (d=0)
{
    X=b/2*a;
    printf("\nX=%f",X);

}
else if (d>0)
{
    X1=(-b+sqrt(d))/(2.0*a);
    X2=(-b-sqrt(d))/(2.0*a);
    printf("\nX1=%f",X1);
    printf("\nX2=%f",X2);

}
else
{
    printf("\nThe Answer is Imaginary Number\n");
}


}
```

I am getting the same answer everytime. it tells me the answer is imaginary number.

Comment: Please edit the code into the question itself, otherwise it's hard to know what you're asking about.

Comment: What the %f? .....

Comment: `==` != `=`. Assignment is not comparison for equality.

Comment: Enable and pay heed to compiler warnings! If your compiler still does not warn, trash it an get a modern one.

Comment: The code you eventually inserted in the question is not the same as you eventually linked to.  This invalidated the answer given by Rahul and that, presumably, is why he is getting downvoted   Don't do that, it is very unfriendly, to put it mildly.  I won't roll it back, but I can edit out the 'f'

Comment: `"%f%f%"` --> Hmmm

Comment: ..and you've stuffed up @Martin Tuskevicius answer too.   If you have to provode such edits, either APPEND the new code, leaving the original as it was, or post a new question, linking it as a follow-on from the old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your first `if` statement:

```
if (d=0)
```

This is not *comparing* `d` to 0, but is *assigning* 0 to `d`.  This expression then takes on the value of the assignment, i.e. 0, which evaluates to false.  That in turn causes `else if (d>0)` to evaluate to false, bringing you to the `else` condition at the end.

Change the assignment operator to a comparison:

```
if (d==0)
```

If you compile with `-Wall -Wextra`, it will warn you of this:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

Comment: thanks. its working now

Answer (score 2):

In the first scanf statement there should be 3 %f you have written only two.

Comment: I'm surprised that there is no warning/error for this.